# Google Assistant conversation action, user response time

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am wondering how long a google assistant conversation action listens for. For example, I have a recipe application. The user queries for individual steps. The user takes ten minutes to finish a step. Does the user need to invoke the action again?

Answer (score 3):

In my own experience developing for a Google Home using Google Assistant there is a very short period of time allowed for silences in the conversation (think seconds). You would definitely need to invoke the assistant again after completing that ten minute task like you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the user will need to invoke the assistant again, but instead of going through all the steps (until the 10 minutes wait) you can create a 'deep link' intent such as 'Ok google, talk to recipe master I want to continue preparing {insert dish name here} after the {10 minutes wait | step x | etc}'

You can see how this is achieved [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-facts-about-google-nodejs)